# Back button not working in XAML / W8

Tags: c#, xaml

I have the following button on my page:

```
 <AppBarButton Grid.Column="0" x:Name="backButton" Icon="Back" Margin="10,26,0,-1"
                      Command="{Binding NavigationHelper.GoBackCommand, ElementName=pageRoot}" 
                      IsEnabled="True"
                      Visibility="Visible"
                      Foreground="Green"

                      AutomationProperties.Name="Back"
                      AutomationProperties.AutomationId="BackButton"
                      AutomationProperties.ItemType="Navigation Button" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      />
```

The button appears but clicking it does nothing.  This was placed on the second of two pages in the application.  I followed the instructions in NavigatonHelper.cs to get it wired up to my second page, but haven't done anything special in the first.  What am I missing?

I even tried tying the `Click` property to a custom function:

```
 public void ClickGoBack(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(HubPage));
    }
```

But this never even got hit when I clicked the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something was put after the top grid in the XAML that overlapped the button - I didn't understand the concept of "natural order" until now.  Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Click existed in AppBarButton defined?

like: `<AppBarButton ... Click="ClickGoBack"></AppBarButton>`

and you should use

```
if (this.Frame.CanGoBack)
{
    this.Frame.GoBack();
}
```

instead of

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(HubPage));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried this but the function ClickGoBack doesn't get hit, despite resolving in the XAML...

Comment: I also don't see any mouseover effect on the button when I try to click it, it's as if it's just an image

Answer (score 0):

You could do this instead much more easier for me.

```
<AppBar><Button Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}" Click="Click1"></Button>
    </AppBar>
```

and for your code behind...

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.GoBack();
    }
```

Comment: its already on the visual studio 2012. just type the code `<Button Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}">` and it will display a windows 8 back button.